# Freelancer API or_search_query

Tags: freelancer.com-api

I want to search for Freelancer projects via their API with multiple query words. I want the projects to match any one of the words in the query and not all of them. Reading through [Freelancer's API](https://developers.freelancer.com/docs/projects/projects#projects-get-5) and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/freelancer/freelancer-sdk-python/issues/38), I expected sending an HTTP GET request to this URL to work (where either one of the two query words, "web" and "mobile", should be matched):

`/projects/0.1/projects/all?query=web mobile&or_search_query=True`

However, the response I get only includes the projects that match both of these words, as if the `or_search_query` parameter is not even there. I have also tried switching "True" to lowercase "true", but the same issue remains.

Comment: Did you try using `+` instead of the space in the `query` filter?

Comment: Just gave it a try. No luck... @ViseshiniReddy